# Parse.com statefulness with users?

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

The [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-current) for Parse's `User` class states:  "Whenever you use any signup or login methods, the user is cached in localStorage."  It gives an example of this using the `Parse.User.current()` call.  But node.js apparently does not have `localStorage`, at least [not by default](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-localstorage).

So, when using Parse in a node.js application, is there any side effect of using `Parse.User.logIn()` or `(new Parse.User).signUp()`?  Is `Parse.User.current()` expected to ever return a non-`null` value?

Specifically, is there any kind of "reset" I need to do in my RESTful layer between calls, if those calls may be made by multiple users *or logged-out users with no session*?  If there is any side effect of the login/signup calls, then I would think that without explicitly logging out the Parse user each time, calls by logged-out users could possibly be mistakenly executed on behalf of whichever logged-in user previously made any RESTful call.

I am aware of the (relatively new) [`Parse.User.become()`](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-become) call, but that would also not apply for a logged-out user.